# Some WFL can add fields but some WFL have no add option

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table, arcgis-online

I'm working on a web map and discovered after publishing there are additional fields I need to add to the attribute table for one of the layers.  Unlike the many other web maps, I have as hosted feature layers, when I go into the Data tab for the map I'm working on, there is no option to add field either in the Table view or Fields view.  I feel like it's some switch I need to flip somewhere, but AGOL is a different place than it was the last time I used it 6 years ago.

Can you help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Hosted feature layers with joined attributes

Refer to BUG-000119730 for more information. A hosted feature layer with joins cannot have its attributes modified.

A workaround is to add the new field before using the Join Features tool. Alternatively, create a relationship class in ArcGIS Pro using the Create Relationship Class tool instead of using a join.